# Django forms are not receiving form data using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am writing a simple AJAX site using a Django back-end where you can create articles. Each article has an edit button, which can be used to modify that pre-existing article on the page. This button pops up an edit form (the issue at hand) in a Bootstrap Modal.

The edit form has only 3 fields: headline, subheading, and a date (for now). Whatever the field inputs are, they are not sent back to Django properly and the `is_valid()` method returns False every single time. This is what `form.errors` gives me as output every single time:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>headline<ul class="errorlist">
<li>This field is required.</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>subheading<ul class="errorlist">
<li>This field is required.</li></ul></li>
<li>date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

The "This field is required" is likely because the model does not have `blank=True`, so the form must be sending empty fields.

Below is all my code in question, including the form in HTML, the AJAX call, and the Django form.

**views.py:**

```
# Handles editing articles
class ArticleEdit(View):
    def post(self, request, id):
        editForm = ArticleForm(request.POST)

        if editForm.is_valid():
            print("Debug: Form is valid")
            # No Logic here yet
            
            return JsonResponse({'edited' : 'OK'}, status=200)
        else:
            print(editForm.errors)
            return JsonResponse({'edited' : 'FAIL'}, status=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['headline', 'subheading', 'date']

        widgets = {
            'headline' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'subheading' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**articles.html**

```
<!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
<div id="editModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Article</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Edit Form -->
        <form class="form-group" method="post" id="editArticleForm">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ editForm }}
          <button type="button" class = "btn btn-outline-success my-3" id="finishEditButton">Finish</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**articles.js**

```
function finishEdit()
{
  editData = $('#editArticleForm').serialize();
  console.log(editData);

  $.ajax
  ({
    url: '/' + currentlyEditing.data('id') + '/edited/',
    data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), data: editData, id: currentlyEditing.data('id')},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data)
    {
      if (data.edited == "OK")
      {
          console.log("EDIT::RESPONSE OK");
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("EDIT::RESPONSE FAIL");
      }
    }
  });
```

I've tried deleting the modal, and having the form as a simple element instead. I've also tried to rewrite my Ajax request but that hasn't worked either. **Plus, the serialized data created from the form displays the information typed into the input fields, but it doesn't end up in Django**.

In conclusion, my whatever my data is in my form in articles.html is not sent properly to Django, no matter what I type, and I cannot seem to figure out the problem. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the console, or have you added any debugging to make sure the URL is correct etc for the ajax call

Comment: @markwalker_ No fatal errors in the console. The specific View that handles this ajax call (ArticleEdit) runs and gives me the ```forms.errors``` output, so I'm fairly certain the URL is correct otherwise I wouldn't get any output. For the record, my urls.py contains ```path('<str:id>/edited/', ArticleEdit.as_view(), name='article_edit_url')```